# List all files that were moved in an email Body - Powershell

Tags: powershell

Trying to accomplish the following:

1)Move files from multiple sources into multiple destinations.
Therefore i listed sources under a SOURCE column, and destinations under a DESTINATION column (WORKING)

2)Send an email with a list of files that were moved and the destination (Not working)

```
Param (
  [string]$SMTPServer = "XXX.XX.xXX",
  [string]$From = "from@email.com",
  [string]$To = "to@email.com",
  [string]$Subject = "New File"
)

Import-Csv -Path "C:\moveallfiles.csv" -ErrorAction Stop | foreach {
if (-not (Test-Path -Path $_.Destination))
{
    # Create directory if needed
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $_.Destination -WhatIf
}
# Copy file
 $MoveFileprocess = Move-Item -Path $_.Source -Destination $_.Destination -force -PassThru
}
 $SMTPMessage = @{
    To = $To
    From = $From
    Subject = "$Subject"
    Smtpserver = $SMTPServer
}
$SMTPBody = "`nThe following files have recently been added `n
          $MoveFileprocess   `n"
Send-MailMessage @SMTPMessage -Body $SMTPBody
```

Right now its listing all the files in one single line, hard to read
I was wondering if theres a way to send the body email as

```
File 1 moved to Destination 1
File 2 moved to Destination 2
```

and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close. Try this:

```
Param (
  [string]$SMTPServer = "XXX.XX.xXX",
  [string]$From = "from@email.com",
  [string]$To = "to@email.com",
  [string]$Subject = "New File"
)
$SMTPBody = "`nThe following files have recently been added `n"
Import-Csv -Path "C:\moveallfiles.csv" -ErrorAction Stop | foreach {
    if (-not (Test-Path -Path $_.Destination)){
        # Create directory if needed
        New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $_.Destination 
    }
    If((Get-Item $_.Source).LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Item $_.Destination).LastWriteTime){
        Move-Item -Path $_.Source -Destination $_.Destination -force
        $SMTPBody += "$($_.Source) moved to $($_.Destination)`n"
    }Else{
        Write-Warning "Skipped overwriting newer $($_.Destination)"
    }
}
$SMTPMessage = @{
    To = $To
    From = $From
    Subject = "$Subject"
    Smtpserver = $SMTPServer
}
Send-MailMessage @SMTPMessage -Body $SMTPBody
```

Note that `Move-Item -PassThru` returns the affected object, not a string. I took out the `-WhatIf` parameter for the `New-Item` command, indented the `foreach{}` loop and made indenting and brackets consistent.

Comment: Thanks Rich, how could i add what files were moved ??? So far I only see the source and Destination. Is it possible to add on the code above, to list for example : " Source > "filename" moved to Destination " And then next line would be file2.txt moved to Destination and so on

Comment: Also move/copy only new files

Comment: Also i tried to move only files for source 2 to Destination 2 -  i received an email saying files were moved source 1 to destination 1 and source 2 to destinatiion 2. I only want new files to be notified

Comment: I added an `If` statement to only copy if newer. See how that works for you.

Comment: Thanks I will take a look.  the move-item i made a variable. $movefiles. I called the $movefiles inside of SMTPBODY, but not able to add a space between names .

Comment: Rich  your update seems to be not working. Email is blank and not moving files. Also avoid to overwrite file - not directory

Comment: Are there any Source files that are newer than the Destination?

Comment: Well - this script will run every hour, if there are new files in source -it will be moved to destination and send an email. If there are no files,  script maybe could send an email. But right now, i created a new file and the email still showing up all the destinations. I only want the destinations where files were moved . Or for example :  file moved to destination1     No files moved to destination 2   Files moved to destinationABC .

Comment: If you've made a change to your code that's not working, please update the full source in the question. You might also want to consider creating a new question if there is something broken that's completely different from the original question about adding file names to an email. I'm happy to help, either way!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205629/discussion-between-user-9191-and-rich-moss).